# How to resolve Null check operator used on a null value on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I tried to fetch data from the subcollection using a logged user ID.
Then display this error
[image]

I tried to fetch it from the firestore sub-collection.The collection name is "users" and doc name is userid

code

```
Future<void> getAmount() async {
    final id = "${loggedInUser.uid}";
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$id/recharge/$id');
    final snapshot = reference.get();

    final result = await snapshot.then(
        (snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Amounts.fromJson(snap.data()!));
    print('result is ====> $result');
    setState(() {
      oneAmount = result;
      loading = false;
    });
  }
```

text widget

```
Text(
            oneAmount!.amount,
            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: kWhite,
              ),
            ),
```

model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Amounts articlesFromJson(String str) => Amounts.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String articlesToJson(Amounts data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Amounts {
  Amounts({
    required this.id,
    required this.amount,
  });
  String id;
  String amount;

  factory Amounts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Amounts(
        id: json["id"] ?? "",
        amount: json["amount"] ?? "",
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "amount": amount,
      };
}
```

Comment: You set "oneAmount = result", but result can be null. "See snap.data() == null ? null : Amounts.fromJson(snap.data()". The error is to return a null and after put a "!" to it.

Comment: (snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Amounts.fromJson(snap.data()));

Comment: Like this? When added like this "argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'." show this error

Comment: Your text widget can't force oneAmount not to be null if you allow oneAmount to be null. You need to manage the null value in your widget like "oneAmount?.amount ?? 'Amount is null'" or be sure to set a value to oneAmount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `!` you can accept null value like

```dart
Text("${oneAmount?.amount}"),
```

Or provide default value on null case

```dart
Text(oneAmount?.amount?? "got NUll"),
```

or do a null check then show widget

```dart
if(oneAmount!=null) Text(oneAmount.amount),
```